# Taking the initial values of an object using useState hook in React

Tags: reactjs

I am printing array of menu items, each has input field type number with quantity to enter for each menu item.
I'm using map function to print put all items, within is the form for each item. The only problem is when I am trying to retrieve the input value of item, the first time is taking the empty object of the useState hook that is setting the value of each item. I don't want that but only, when the value is changed. Beside that when I am clicking on arrows up and down the value of input filed  is not increasing.
Can somebody help?

Here is my code of Meals.js:

```
import {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import CartContext from "./store/CartContext";
const Meals = () => {
    const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
    const [meal, setMeal] = useState({});
    const cartCtx = useContext(CartContext);

    const fetchMeals = () => {
        fetch('https://food-order-7d9f9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/meals.json')
            .then(response => response.json() )
            .then(data => {
                const loadedMeals = [];
                for(let key in data){
                    loadedMeals.push({
                        id: key,
                        meal: data[key].name,
                        description: data[key].description,
                        price: data[key].price,
                        quantity: 1
                    })
                }
                setMeals(loadedMeals);
            })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
            fetchMeals();

        }, [])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        cartCtx.addItem(meal)
        console.log("Iz submitHandler:")
        console.log(cartCtx.items)

    }
    const handleChange = (e, id, inputMeal, description, price) =>{
        let updatedMeal =  {
            id: id,
            meal: inputMeal,
            description: description,
            price: price,
            quantity: +e.target.value
        }

        setMeal(updatedMeal)
        console.log("Meal object value");
        console.log(meal);

        const updatedItemIndex = meals.findIndex(
            i => i.id === id
        )
        const updatedMeals = [
            ...meals.slice(0, updatedItemIndex),
            updatedMeal,
            ...meals.slice(updatedItemIndex + 1)
        ]


        console.log("From handleChange:");
        console.log(updatedMeals)

        updatedMeal =  {
            id: "",
            meal: "",
            description: "",
            price: "",
            quantity: ""
        }


    }
    return(
        <>
            {
                meals.map(meal => {
                    return(
                        <div  key={meal.id}>
                            <div>
                                <div>{meal.meal}</div>
                                <div>{meal.description}</div>
                                <div>{meal.price}€</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-wrapper">
                                <form onSubmit={ e=> submitHandler(e, meal.id, meal.meal, meal.description, meal.price)}>
                                    <input
                                        label="Amount"
                                        name={`${meal.id}`}
                                        min="1"
                                        max="5"
                                        type="number"
                                        value={meal.quantity}
                                        onChange={e => handleChange(e, meal.id, meal.meal, meal.description, meal.price)}
                                    />
                                    <button>+ Add</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        </>
    )
}
export default Meals;
```

and my demo uploaded on codesandbox.io:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-williamson-puptl?file=/src/store/CartProvider.js

Answer (score 1):

Your `handleChange` function is wrong, On click of up and down arrow, just get the item that is being updated and update its `count` property.

I also updated the `submitHandler`.

Here is the updated Code- I hope it solves your problem .

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import CartContext from "./store/CartContext";
const Meals = () => {
  const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
  const cartCtx = useContext(CartContext);

  const fetchMeals = () => {
    fetch("https://food-order-7d9f9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/meals.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const loadedMeals = [];
        for (let key in data) {
          loadedMeals.push({
            id: key,
            meal: data[key].name,
            description: data[key].description,
            price: data[key].price,
            quantity: 1
          });
        }
        setMeals(loadedMeals);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMeals();
  }, []);

  const submitHandler = (e, mealId) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const updatedItemIndex = meals.findIndex((i) => i.id === mealId);
    const meal = meals[updatedItemIndex];
    console.log(cartCtx.items);

    cartCtx.addItem({ ...meal });

  };
  const handleChange = (e, id, inputMeal, description, price) => {
    let updatedMeal = {
      id: id,
      meal: inputMeal,
      description: description,
      price: price,
      quantity: +e.target.value
    };

    const updatedItemIndex = meals.findIndex((i) => i.id === id);
    const newMeals = [...meals];
    newMeals[updatedItemIndex] = updatedMeal;
    setMeals(newMeals);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {meals.map((meal) => {
        return (
          <div key={meal.id}>
            <div>
              <div>{meal.meal}</div>
              <div>{meal.description}</div>
              <div>{meal.price}€</div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-wrapper">
              <form
                onSubmit={(e) =>
                  submitHandler(
                    e,
                    meal.id,
                    meal.meal,
                    meal.description,
                    meal.price
                  )
                }
              >
                <input
                  label="Amount"
                  name={`${meal.id}`}
                  min="1"
                  max="5"
                  type="number"
                  value={meal.quantity}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    handleChange(
                      e,
                      meal.id,
                      meal.meal,
                      meal.description,
                      meal.price
                    )
                  }
                />
                <button>+ Add</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
export default Meals;
```

Comment: partially, still with const [meal, setMeal] = useState({});  meal is set to empty object, and I want to bypass that and to set it to first changed value, as well as same when submitting the form. I want to bypass the initialization of meals on empty array const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);, and to catch only when the meal is injected into this array.

Comment: what do you mean by bypaas? you are fetching meals from api , so initially `meals` array will be empty. so `const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);` is fine. But you want to store a `meal` and its value will be any one of the meal from the list which gets updated first. am i right?

Comment: Yes, I want to store the meal, but when you first time change the value of any input field it is being printed empty object {} not the value of the meal that u have selected. Try this: console.log("Meal object value"); console.log(meal); I want to bypass that, and only to save the changed value, not empty object.